# How to solve equation involving maximum on one side of the equation

Tags: r, math, statistics, discrete-mathematics

This may sound trivial but I would appreciate if someone can help with me out.

```
y= max(m*k,u)
```

find m.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Is m supposed to be variable while k and u are fixed? Are there any constraints like all are positive numbers?

Comment: y, k and u are given I have to obtain the value of m. need to obtain an expression for m from the equation.

Comment: Are y, k, and u just single numbers or arrays? If they are just numbers its trivial. If y=u then the value of k does not matter as longs as m*k <= u. If y>u the y=m*k and k=y/m.

Comment: They are array of number. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

m = y/k if y is smaller than u.

If y=u, then m could have any value greater of equal to y/k.

If y is greater than u, then something went wrong since y is out of range of the max expression.